# Using an if statment referencing a variable not in workspace

Tags: r

I would like to create a function that can deal with an object that may or may not have been created yet.

At the beginning of this function, I would like to have a quick "if" statement declaring if a certain variable has been created yet. In this case, a time stamp.

```
TS<-date()

fun<-function(){
if(TS=="")
{print("No Time Stamp Info")}
else
{print("Time Stamp created at"); TS}
}
```

or alternatively

```
TS<-date()

fun<-function(){
if(is.character(TS))
{print("Time Stamp created at"); TS}
else
{print("No Time Stamp Info")}
}
```

But of course if we remove the time stamp and just have the following without first assigning any value to TS:

```
#TS<-date()

fun<-function(){
if(TS=="")
{print("No Time Stamp Info")}
else
{print("Time Stamp created at"); TS}
}
```

Than I throw an error because TS does not exist. I would like to find a way so that if there is no variable "TS" in the R workspace, I get the "No Time Stamp Info" , as opposed to an error

Is there anyway to correctly set up a function that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
if (exists("TS")) ...
```

this will return `TRUE` if `TS` exists.

Comment: if(!exists("TS")) looks promising

Comment: +1 I forgot about `exists` like the German national team forgot about winning.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps include

```
if("TS" %in% ls())
```

to see if `TS` is defined first.

And if `TS` would only be defined in the `.GlobalEnv` , then you would need to include

```
if("TS" %in% ls(envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

instead, possible changing the `envir` argument according to the environment in which "TS" might be created.